# Use sed to copy to the previous line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to convert:

```
A,p
B,q
C,r
D,s
```

Into:

```
A,p,q
B,q,r
C,r,s
```

Using `sed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `sed` isn't the thing for this (and others may know how to do it much better with `sed`), but here goes:

```
$ sed '2,$ s/.$/&,&/' file | sed -r ':a;N;s/\n(.)(,?.?)(,.)$/\3\n\1\2/;ta' | sed '$d'
A,p,q
B,q,r
C,r,s
```

#### Notes

`sed '2,$ s/.$/&,&/'` means duplicate the last character on all but the first line, adding a comma:

- `2,$` from the 2nd line onwards
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `.$` the last character
- `&` the matched pattern

`sed -r ':a;N;s/\n(.)(,?.?)(,.)$/\3\n\1\2/;ta;'` means take the last character from each line after the first one and stick it on the end of the previous line:

- `-r` use ERE
- `:a` label: execute from here
- `;` separates commands
- `N` read the next line into the pattern space so we can use `\n` to represent newlines in the pattern
- `(.)` save one character for later
- `?` zero or one of the preceding character
- `$` end of line
- `\1` reference to saved pattern
- `ta` if the last `s` command was successful, branch to `:a` and execute the loop again
- `$d` delete the last line

If your file does not have only single characters between the commas, you won't be able to use the very simple regex above. Here is a version that works if the file is comma separated. For example, given

```
January,apple
February,pear
March,kiwi
April,mango
```

You could do this, which also works if there *is* only one character, of course

```
$ sed '2,$ s/[^,]*$/&,&/' file | sed -r ':a;N;s/\n([^,]*)(,?[^,]*)(,[^,]*)$/\3\n\1\2/;ta;' | sed '$d'
January,apple,pear
February,pear,kiwi
March,kiwi,mango
```

`sed` scripts can be written on multiple lines. I can't claim this significantly improves readability ;) but it may be more portable since there are restrictions on the use of `;` in non-GNU versions of `sed`:

```
sed '2,$ s/[^,]*$/&,&/' file |
sed -r '{:a
          N
          s/\n([^,]*)(,?[^,]*)(,[^,]*)$/\3\n\1\2/
          ta}' |
sed '$d'
```

`[^,]*` means zero or more characters that aren't commas.

Comment: You can do it in a single invocation I think: `sed -nr '$!{:a;N;s/(.*)\n(.*)(,[^,]*)/\1\3\n\2\3/;P;D;ba;}'`

Comment: @steeldriver awesome! I'm laughing because it didn't occur to me to reuse `\3` etc instead of copying the pattern first! Thanks for teaching how to give a loop an address. I think you should go ahead and post your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it in a single sed invocation I think:

```
sed -nE '$!{:a;N;s/(.*)\n(.*)(,[^,]*$)/\1\3\n\2\3/;P;D;ba;}' file
A,p,q
B,q,r
C,r,s
```

## Explanation

The `:a;N;...P;D;ba` structure essentially maintains a 2-line buffer, within which we can split the fields and copy/move groups of characters around:

```
$!{                                   # For any line except the last
  :a                                  # Enter a loop:
  N                                   # Append the following line, after a newline  
  s/(.*)\n(.*)(,[^,]*)$/\1\3\n\2\3/   # Capture (1) up to the newline, 
                                      # (2) from the newline to the last comma, 
                                      # and (3) everything else into groups and 
                                      # copy group 3 before the newline
  P                                   # Print everything up to the newline
  D                                   # Delete everything up to the newline, 
                                      # ready for the next iteration
  ba
}
```

Note that use of the `-E` (or `-r`) extended regex is not a requirement - it just reduces the amount of escaping that's needed.